# get table row when button is clicked

Tags: jquery

I have a button (actually several buttons) that add table rows dynamically.  On each button click I need to show/hide specific elements in the table row.

The first time one of the buttons is clicked, the first row is added in the table.  I'm using the following to determine what button is clicked:

```
        j$('[id$=btnContact]').click(function(){
            console.log('contact button was clicked');
            var dataRows = j$('tr.dataRow');
            console.log(dataRows);
        });
```

The problem is that the dataRows object is empty on the first click because the first row is getting created.  Is there a way to access the dataRows object when the row is created?

Is a callback function needed?

Since the dataRows object is empty, I cannot show/hide the elements in that row.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If you could throw a jsfiddle example it would probably be way easier to help...

Comment: It's not clear what you need, why not create the row first and then show/hide the elements?

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding rows dynamically, then you need to bind the event differently. For instance, if you have the following:

**Markup**:

```
<table id="tbl">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="button" class="btnAddRow" value="Add Row" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**jQuery**:

```
$(".btnAddRow").click(function(){
    var row = $(this).parent().parent().clone();
    $("#tbl").append(row);
});
```

**jsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/hescano/aU4DQ/

it will only work for the first button. While the following will work for all buttons added dynamically to the DOM, or not:

```
$(document).on("click", ".btnAddRow", function(){
    var row = $(this).parent().parent().clone();
    $("#tbl").append(row);
});
```

**jsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/hescano/aU4DQ/1/

The latter is an *event delegate*, and you can obtain more information here: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0):

Well the simplest way to do it is.

```
 var row = $(this).closest('tr');
```